# How do you prove by definition that $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty\\y\to\infty}\frac{2x+3y}{x^2-xy+y^2}=0$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> prove by definition $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty\\y\to\infty}\frac{2x+3y}{x^2-xy+y^2}=0$

the original question was just to calculate that limit , but I'm pretty confident it's 0, however I am having a hard time proving it by definition.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Try switching to polar coordinates. In this case the limit will be taken as r goes to infinity.

Comment: @zbrads2 that doesn't seem a good approach, since $r\to\infty$ is stronger ($x\to \infty$, $y \to \infty$ implies $r\to\infty$ but not in viceversa)

Comment: @JulianMejia Thanks for pointing that out. I think this method would work if the limit was being taken as $x,y\to0$ if one can show that the limit is independent of $\theta$, yes?

Comment: @zbrads2, Exactly, $x\to 0$,$y\to 0$ iff $r\to 0$. So that's why this method works in this case.

Comment: I think that polar coordinates **can** be used here. It is easy to show that the denominator is $\ge r^2/2$. The absolute value of the numerator is at most $\sqrt{13}r$. So the limit of this ratio when $r\to\infty$ is equal to zero. It follows that the limit when $x\to\infty,y\to\infty$ is then also zero. This only works because limit when $r\to\infty$ happens to exist. The problem Julian Mejia pointed out would be relevant in a case this limit would exist, but the more general one would not. For example $f(x,y)=e^{-x-y}/(x^2+y^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$x^2-xy+y^2=\frac12x^2+\frac12y^2+\frac12(x-y)^2,$$you have that$$\frac x{x^2-xy+y^2}\leqslant\frac x{\frac12x^2}=\frac2x$$and$$\frac y{x^2-xy+y^2}\leqslant\frac y{\frac12y^2}=\frac2y.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Neat. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.